# Changing the equivalency value in if state

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
com=input('> ')
while True:
    if com=='say':
        print('1')
        com=input('> ')
    if com=='change':
        global change_com
        change_com=input('changeing_say_to: ')
        change_com='say'
        com=input('> ')
```

I wanna the result is that after `change_com=input('changeing_say_to: ')` , the `change_com` becomes something except `say`, like `NAME` and then again when I give `NAME` instead of `say` to the value of `com`, it would go to `if com=='say'` state. How can I do this?

Here is the target:

```
        > say
        1
        > change
        changeing_say_to: NAME
        > NAME
        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare against the current value of `change_com` instead of hardcoded `say` - and move your nested `input("> ")`-calls up to the beginning of your while loop. Also provide a way to leave the loop (beside Ctrl-C) :

```
change_com = "say"

while True:
    com = input('> ')
    if com == change_com:
        print('1')
    elif com == 'change':
        change_com = input('changing {} to: '.format(change_com))
    elif com == "break":
        break
```

You can use a string-format param to adjust your message so it matches whatever curently sits in `change_com`.

See [str.format(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Output:

```
> say
1
> say
1
> change
changing say to: tut
> tut
1
> tut
1
> change
changing tut to: lol
> lol
1
> break
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
value='say'
while True:
    com = input('> ')
    if com == value:
        print('1')
    elif com == 'change':
        value=input('changeing_say_to: ')
```